# How do I make child controls in Collection behave as child controls and/or get skin applied?

Tags: c#, themes, asp.net-3.5, custom-server-controls

I am trying to create a server control with child controls that are exclusively derived from a particular class.  The child controls in this case are all custom server controls also.  This particular web application uses a Skin file to apply styles to these child controls.

Previously, these child controls were only used as child controls of another server control that allowed any markup.  The skin works fine, though there are some deficiencies with this model.

The old model -- which I must still support for legacy compatibility reasons -- looked something like

```
<myns:FieldPanel ID="SomeId" runat="server" LabelText="SomeLabelText">
    <myns:SomeFieldControl ID="SomeControlName" runat="server" SomeProperty="false" />
    <myns:SomeOtherFieldControl ID="AnotherControl" runat="server" SomeProperty="false">
        <Items>
            <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="1" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Dos" Value="2" />
            <asp:ListItem Text="Trois" Value="3" />
        </Items>
    </myns:SomeOtherFieldControl>
</myns:FieldPanel>
```

The `FieldPanel` control is defined like

```
[ParseChildren(false)]
public class FieldPanel : WebControl
{
    public override void RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        // some rendering
    }

    public override void RenderEndTag(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        // some more rendering
    }

    public string PanelLabelCssClass { get; set; }

    public string LabelText { get; set; }
}
```

Both `SomeFieldControl` and `SomeOtherFieldControl` inherit from an abstract base class called `Field`.

Similar markup that would use my new server control would be

```
<myns:FieldTablePanel ID="AnotherId" runat="server" LabelText="OtherLabelText">
    <Fields>
        <myns:SomeFieldControl ID="SomeControlName" runat="server" SomeProperty="false" />
        <myns:SomeOtherFieldControl ID="AnotherControl" runat="server" SomeProperty="false">
            <Items>
                <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="1" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Dos" Value="2" />
                <asp:ListItem Text="Trois" Value="3" />
            </Items>
        </myns:SomeOtherFieldControl>
     </Fields>
</myns:FieldTablePanel>
```

`FieldTablePanel` has a lot more code than `FieldPanel`, but some basics:

```
[DefaultProperty(null)]
[ParseChildren(true)]
public class FieldTablePanel : FieldPanel, INamingContainer
{
    private FieldCollection _fields;
    private Table _innerTable;

    public class FieldCollection : Collection<Field>, INamingContainer
    {
        // mainly standard Collection methods that I have to do something special with
    }

    [Bindable(false)]
    [DefaultValue(null)]
    [TemplateContainer(typeof(FieldCollection))]
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]
    // Note that FieldCollection does not work here
    public Collection<Field> Fields
    {
        get
        {
            return _fields;
        }

        set
        {
            _innerTable.Rows.Clear();
            _fields = new FieldCollection(_innerTable, Page, value);
        }
    }
}
```

I left out a lot of methods here, of course.  I have everything rendering the way I want *except* that the skins are not applied to `SomeFieldControl` and `SomeOtherFieldControl` as they should be.  Further, when running the code, both `Parent` and `Page` for `SomeFieldControl` and `SomeOtherFieldControl` are `null`.  This is not the case in the legacy example.

I would like to avoid just using `ITemplate` for the collection of inner controls unless there is no other way, since I am relying on all the child controls being derived from `Field`.  What am I missing here?  I can provide more code on request.

**Edit:**

The skin file (Site.skin, in this case) has an entry for each of the custom `Field` controls as well as `FieldPanel` and `FieldTablePanel`.  The relevant portions:

```
<myns:FieldPanel runat="server"
  PanelLabelCssClass="formPanelLabel"
  Width="100%"
/>

<myns:FieldTablePanel runat="server"
  PanelLabelCssClass="formPanelLabel"
  Width="100%"
/>

<myns:SomeFieldControl runat="server"
  LabelCssClass="formFieldLabel"
  ResourceClassKey="CommonResource"
  RequiredErrorMessageResourceKey="RequiredMessageFormat"
/>

<myns:SomeOtherFieldControl runat="server"
  LabelCssClass="formFieldLabel"
  RequiredErrorMessageResourceKey="RequiredMessageFormat"
  ResourceClassKey="CommonResource"
  ChooseOneResourceKey="ChooseOneOption"
  NoneResourceKey="NoneOption"
/>
```

I did make a slight edit to the definition of `FieldPanel` above to include the correct property name `PanelLabelCssClass`, which is a CSS class that gets applied to a particular label.  The `Field` base class has a property called `LabelCssClass` which, again, applies a CSS class to a label within the control (which works when the control is within `FieldPanel` but not when the control is within the `<Fields>` section of `FieldTablePanel`).

The relevant CSS:

```
.formFieldLabel
{
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, san;
    font-size: smaller;
}

.formPanelLabel
{
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, san;
    color: #666666;
    font-size: x-small;
}
```

**Another Edit:**

To my `FieldTablePanel` class definition, I got rid of my custom override of `Controls` (which just basically returned the field collection) and added:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    if (_fields != null)
    {
        _fields.ToList<Field>().ForEach(this.Controls.Add);
    }
}
```

No luck.  The skins are still not being applied to the `Field` controls.

The reason I initially had an override on `Controls` was to try to ensure that getting `Controls` would return a `ControlCollection` that was in sync with `Fields` at all times.  I added similar code to the setter in my `Fields` property (specifically, adding `this.Controls.Clear();` and `_fields.ToList().ForEach(this.Controls.Add);` at appropriate places) with no change in results.  I could try manipulating the `FieldCollection to ensure that when a Field is added that it is added to the Control collection, but I don't know whether that would help.`

One more thing I did try was adding my inner `Table` as a Control of FieldTablePanel, but doing so just gave me the error

> Multiple controls with the same ID '...' were found.  Trace requires that controls have unique IDs.

when going to the page with the control.

Comment: provide please content of skin file. I assume that I've missed something, cause at my test soulution all skins were applied

Comment: @IceN I have included the relevant portions of the Skin file and CSS.  Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for details! I am still can't reproduce described situation. If you whant I can share my test project. I assume that the problem some where at the control including logic, when you are adding them to table. In my project I've simplify it to:  public FieldCollection(Control table, Page page,Collection<Field> fields)
            {
                foreach (var field in fields)
                {
                    table.Controls.Add(field);
                }
            }

Comment: @IceN For whatever reason, I'm missing something here.  I see what it appears you are doing, but I'm having trouble doing something similar.  See my "Another Edit."  Also, in your simplified version, wouldn't the entire `Field` control be rendered?  That could be an issue, since the whole point of the `FieldTablePanel` control is to change how the `Field` controls render from how they would render in any other context.